# What's so special about 659 and 133

Tags: riddle

To an American civilian, there's only one other number like it; to a solider there is that one and two more as well.

Hint

> This came to me while I was trying to fall asleep and staring at something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The numbers all "fit together" with no spaces on a digital clock.  833 is the other "civilian" number; 1333 works on 24-hour time.

Comment: There's a second one that works for military, but since I didn't ask that, you still get the check.

Comment: @Foon But then 0133 does not fit this rule for military time, correct?

Comment: True, but 033 (which is what I thought at least some clock shows as opposed to 0033) does